# how to rectify entity ID does not exist?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am trying to create a simple plugin that sends email, but the content Outputparameter ID that is passed as an argument in sendEmail method returns throws an error:

> ---entity with id = xxxxxxx does not exist

```
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
{
    Entity travelDetail = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

    if (travelDetail.LogicalName != "gg_traveldetail") { return; }

    try
    {

        EntityReference sConRef = travelDetail.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("gg_consultantstaffingrole");
        EntityReference sNurRef = travelDetail.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("gg_nursestaffingrole");

        if (travelDetail.Attributes.Contains("gg_bookingcomplete"))
        {
            if (travelDetail.GetAttributeValue<bool>("gg_bookingcomplete"))
            {

                Guid userId = ((WhoAmIResponse)service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;

                Guid travelregardingobjectid = Guid.Empty; // new Guid(context.OutputParameters["id"].ToString());
                string regardingobject = string.Empty;//"gg_traveldetail";
                string emailSubject = "A travel detail has just been completed";
                string emailBody = "Plesae refer to the completed travel that has just been completed by either a consultant or a nurse";

                if (context.OutputParameters.Contains("id"))
                {
                    travelregardingobjectid = new Guid(context.OutputParameters["id"].ToString());
                    regardingobject = "gg_traveldetail";
                }

                if (sConRef != null)
                {

                    //Entity image = (Entity)context.PreEntityImages["ImageDist"];

                    Entity conRef = service.Retrieve(sConRef.LogicalName, sConRef.Id, new ColumnSet(true));

                    EntityReference con = conRef.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_consultant");

                    Entity consultant = service.Retrieve(con.LogicalName, con.Id, new ColumnSet(new string[] { "new_name", "emailaddress" }));


                    //Entity email = new Entity("email");
                    SendEmail(service, consultant, consultant.Id, userId, travelregardingobjectid, emailBody, emailSubject, regardingobject);
                }
```

Getting the error at the sendemail method,the sendEmail full code is below and its parameters:

```
private void SendEmail
        (IOrganizationService service,Entity receiever, Guid recieverUserId, Guid senderUserId, Guid regardingObjectId, string emailBody, string emailSubject, string entity)

    {

        Entity email = new Entity();
        email.LogicalName = "email";

        //Set regarding object property (i.e. The entity record, which u want this email associated with)

        EntityReference regardingObject = new EntityReference(entity, regardingObjectId);
        email.Attributes.Add("regardingobjectid", regardingObject);

        Entity fromParty = new Entity("activityparty");
        fromParty["addressused"] = "victor@geek-guru.co.uk";
        EntityReference from = new EntityReference("systemuser", senderUserId);
        fromParty.Attributes.Add("partyid", from);

        //Derive to party

        Entity toParty = new Entity("activityparty");
        toParty["addressused"] = "victor@geek-guru.co.uk";
        EntityReference to = new EntityReference(receiever.LogicalName, recieverUserId);
        toParty.Attributes.Add("partyid", to);

        EntityCollection collFromParty = new EntityCollection();
        collFromParty.EntityName = "systemuser";
        collFromParty.Entities.Add(fromParty);

        EntityCollection collToParty = new EntityCollection();
        collToParty.EntityName = "systemuser";
        collToParty.Entities.Add(toParty);

        email.Attributes.Add("from", collFromParty);
        email.Attributes.Add("to", collToParty);

        //Set subject & body properties
        email.Attributes.Add("subject", emailSubject);
        email.Attributes.Add("description", emailBody);

        //Create email activity

        Guid emailID = service.Create(email);

        //Sending email

        SendEmailRequest reqSendEmail = new SendEmailRequest();
        reqSendEmail.EmailId = emailID;//ID of created mail
        //reqSendEmail.TrackingToken = "";
        reqSendEmail.IssueSend = true;

        SendEmailResponse res = (SendEmailResponse)service.Execute(reqSendEmail);

    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing clear about what your code is doing and what you are trying to achieve. Which line of code throws the exception? Who populates value in `context.OutputParameters` ?

Comment: hi @ChetanRanpariya, I am trying to send an email when i finish creating a record and it throws an erro when it gets to the sendEmail metho here --SendEmail(service, consultant, consultant.Id, userId, travelregardingobjectid, emailBody, emailSubject, regardingobject); saying the regardingbject id, which is the entity in my context is missing.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have also added my full code.

Comment: Considering that the exception is happening in `SendEmail()`, you might to post that code as well.

Comment: @Aron hi Aron, i have added the full code.

Comment: Which line in `SendEmail` method throws the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you verify if this is synchronous or asynchronous? Switch & test. Is this working when it’s not debugged?

Also comment out the below line & try to set a different regarding.

```
EntityReference regardingObject = new EntityReference(entity, regardingObjectId);
```

May be for example: this will set sender as regarding. Let’s see if this works.

```
EntityReference regardingObject = new EntityReference("systemuser", senderUserId);
```

My guess is the DB transaction of creating travel detail record is not yet committed, hence creation of email record failed with this error, where you are referring created record as regarding.

[Good link](https://nishantrana.me/2009/01/21/understanding-inputparameters-and-outputparameters-of-plugin-context-in-crm40/) to learn about inputparameters and outputparameters of plugin context.

It doesn’t matter from where you are getting the Id (primary key), it should work.

`context.PrimaryEntityId` or `((Entity)InputParameters("Target")).Id` or `context.OutputParameters["id"].ToString()`

References:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/201585

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/201583